# Where to I put house wrap on my brick exterior wall?

Tags: insulation, framing, brick, house-wrap

We bought an older house that has a crawl space in southern Mississippi. When I took out the existing drywall, it was hung on 1x4 strips attached to brick with masonry nails and there's a gap between the wood flooring and brick - maybe an inch.  My original thought was to put house wrap against the brick, install 2x4 stud framing, attaching to the flooring and roof beams, add insulation and then drywall.

I've seen where people have said in different climates house wrap goes against the brick or between the insulation and the drywall.  Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Brick --> House Wrap --> Framing/Insulation --> Drywall???  Would this allow the brick to naturally sweat and not adversely affect the insulation and/or drywall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really need a vapor barrier there. If this was a basement wall, that would be different, but basements are very uncommon in your area. Your above-grade brick should not be sweating in general. That's why the furring strips were mounted to the bare brick. Mere humidity should not be wicking into the bricks like that. Your A/C will keep any transient humidity low inside your home.

What tends to throw people off here, is they're used to stick-built homes and using standard kraft-paper batts inside the studs. For non-brick (or cinder block) homes, a vapor barrier is a must.